# How to perform if else correctly?

Tags: powershell

I face the problem after perform the conversion successfully in If... it still go to else... any better way to solve?

```
if((Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "D:\Temp" "Folder A") -eq $null)

{
    checkProfileThenConvert # Here I perform the conversion and now D:\Temp\Folder A exists
}
else
{
    Remove-Item "D:\Temp\Folder A" -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
    checkProfileThenConvert

}
```

Comment: [If you need to compare a value to `$null` you should put $null on the left-hand side of the comparison. When you compare `$null` to an `Object` the result is False because the comparison object is an array. When you compare an array to $null, the comparison filters out any $null values stored in the array.](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)

Comment: What you mean? Can show me how to make it? ><
For example if I put this line in if it will proceed to else 
New-Item -Path "D:\Temp\Folder A" -ItemType Directory

Comment: `if($Null -eq (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "D:\Temp" "Folder A")) {...`

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have access to your file system, I can't validate whether there somewhere a (hidden) `Folder A` down the `D:\Temp` folder tree...

Neverteless, a common mistake with comparing against `$Null` is actually described in the note of the [**About Comparison Operators**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7):

> If you need to compare a value to `$null` you should put `$null` on
>   the left-hand side of the comparison. When you compare `$null` to an
>   `Object[]` the result is False because the comparison object is an
>   array. When you compare an array to `$null`, the comparison filters
>   out any `$null` values stored in the array. For example:

```
PS> $null -ne $null, "hello"
True
PS> $null, "hello" -ne $null
hello
```

In your case, the correct syntax should at least be:

```
if($null -eq (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "D:\Temp" "Folder A"))

{
    checkProfileThenConvert  \\Here I perform the convertion and now D:\Temp\Folder A exists
}
else
{
    Remove-Item "D:\Temp\Folder A" -Recurse -Force -Confirm:$false
    checkProfileThenConvert

}
```